# How to change column name in Python using For loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-science

I have created dictionary where key is actual column name and value is the name i want to change. below is what i am trying to do as for each value in data frame change name = rename value.

```
def renaming_columns(headers):
rename_list = dict.fromkeys(headers)
for i in headers:
    display(i)
    rename_list[i] = input("Please enter relevant name: ")
return rename_list

renamed_column_name = renaming_columns(headers)

for i in renamed_column_name:
    datafram = datafram.rename(columns={renamed_column_name.keys()[i]:renamed_column_name[i]})
```

Comment: please indent your code properly.

Comment: Hi Prakhar, you code has some syntax issues. you need to fix them first

Comment: That what i need, my intent is to change column name, so for every column name i want that column name which is key of dictionary should be replaced with the value of the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `renaming_columns` function returns a dictionary, you can use the dictionary to rename all the columns at the same time.

```
headers = datafram.columns  # current column names
renamed_column_name = renaming_columns(headers)  # get new names

datafram = datafram.rename(columns=renamed_column_name)  # rename all columns
```

Answer (score 0):

If like you suggested, `datafram` is a dictionary, then this should work:

```py
def renaming_columns(headers):
    rename_list = dict.fromkeys(headers)
    for i in headers:
        display(i)
        rename_list[i] = input("Please enter relevant name: ")
        return rename_list

renamed_column_name = renaming_columns(headers)

for i in renamed_column_name:
    datafram[renamed_column_name[i]] = datafram.pop(i)
```

However, your naming of these variables is very misleading: `rename_list` is a dictionary but you named it `list`; `datafram` is usually considerred as `pandas dataframe`.

Comment: This worked thanks, also I understand the confusion will keep that in mind. Thanks for the help,